# Redux Dev Tools For WebStorm

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, redux, webstorm

I was wondering if there are any redux tools that integrate with WebStorm. Something like the Chrome one but a direct integration into WebStorm debugger.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Please vote for the related request on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20053)